# JavaScript in IntelliJ rest client

Tags: javascript, rest, client, jetbrains-ide

I have read most if not all of the documentation JetBrains provides about their HTTP Client and how to create requests using files with .http extension.

My problem is that I want to use a function in a different .js file inside one of the .http request files. The way they explain how this can be achieved is with this 1 liner "For external scripts, you need to enable it manually."  The problem is they don't explain how you do the manual part. I did find that you have add any custom js code/library via `Settings-> Languages and Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries`.

So my question is if anyone knows how to import custom JavaScript in a different location in a .http file? My JavaScript function is written in this manner:

```
export default function writeResponse(response, client) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

> For external scripts, you need to enable it manually

This quote [from the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.1/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#using-response-handler-scripts) is about enabling code assistance for external script, not about importing and exporting functions from scripts.

For your scenario, please try `load()`, for example:

```
### Import a function check() from a script new.js
GET http://example.org

> {%
load('/Users/YourPathToScript/scripts/new.js');
check();
 %}
```